# Mensagens automáticas de resumo de edição em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Editei uma pergunta no Stack Overflow em Português e esqueci de colocar um resumo de edição. O site preencheu o resumo de edição com:

> Added x characters in body

Depois reparei que várias edições estão também com a frase em inglês.

Comment: Provavelmente também acontece com `x chars in title` e `changed tags`

Comment: thanks for reporting, I'm on it

Comment: @m0sa, could you please check this one also: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/640/corrigir-traducao-de-reviews-all-time

Comment: @m0sa also, I've flagged other translation problems too recently, by the way (just mentioned 'cause I don't know how the flag visibility works in details to the SE staff).

Comment: that would be @Gabe, he has the _override-translations_ powers too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've localized the code that generates these revision auto comments. Expect them to be translated in a `2014.4.17.*` build rev. Note however, that only edits after will have localized auto-generated comments.

Comment: No problem. My concern is for the future. Thanks a lot!